# Waiting for two onChange to trigger with MediatorLiveData

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to learn how to use MediatorLiveData as described here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData
What I want to do is wait for two livedata object to get an update then do some logic on both.

So in my activity i currently got this. While this works I'm currently only getting Orders while i would like to wait for Orders AND Orderrows to finish and then make some change.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button myButt;
    private MainViewModel mvw;
    private TextView myView;
    private MediatorLiveData data;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mvw = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myButt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        myView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        myButt.setOnClickListener(this);

        data =  new MediatorLiveData<>();
        data.addSource(mvw.getAllOrders(), new Observer<Orders>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Orders orders) {
                data.setValue(orders);
            }
        });
        data.addSource(mvw.getAllOrderRows(), new Observer<OrderRows>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(OrderRows orderRows) {
                        data.setValue(orderRows);

                    }
        });
        data.observe(this, new Observer<Orders>() { //this observers Orders but how do i get orders AND orderrows?
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(Orders order) {
                        myView.setText(mvw.extractDate(order)); 
                         //Here i want to manipulate order and orderrows
                        Log.i("livedata" , order.getOrders().toString());
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                Log.i("button","clicked");
                mvw.updateOrderData(); // calls for new values to be fetched
                mvw.updateOrderRowData();
        }
    }
}
```

in my viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private GetOrder getOrderRepo;
    private MutableLiveData<Orders> allOrders;
    private MutableLiveData<OrderRows> allOrderRows;


    public MainViewModel(){
        getOrderRepo = new GetOrder();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Orders> getAllOrders() {
        if(allOrders == null){
            allOrders = new MutableLiveData<>();
            allOrders = getOrderRepo.getAllOrders();
        }
        return  allOrders;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<OrderRows> getAllOrderRows() {
        if(allOrderRows == null){
            allOrderRows = new MutableLiveData<>();
            allOrderRows = getOrderRepo.getAllOrderRows();
        }
        return allOrderRows;
    }

    public void updateOrderData(){
        Log.i("updating","updating data");
        Orders orders = getOrderRepo.getAllOrders().getValue();
        allOrders.setValue(orders);
    }
    public void updateOrderRowData(){
        Log.i("updating","updating data");
        OrderRows orderRows = getOrderRepo.getAllOrderRows().getValue();
        allOrderRows.setValue(orderRows);
    }

    public String extractDate(Orders orders){
        ArrayList<Order> listOfOrders = orders.getOrders();
        Log.i("extractDate", ""+(listOfOrders.size()-1));
        String date = listOfOrders.get(listOfOrders.size()-1).getOrderTime();
        return date;
    }

}
```

In the repostiory.

```
public class GetOrder {
    private ApiService mAPIService;
    MutableLiveData<Orders> allOrders;
    MutableLiveData<OrderRows> allOrderRows;

    public GetOrder(){
        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
        allOrders = new MutableLiveData<Orders>();
        allOrderRows = new MutableLiveData<OrderRows>();
    }
    public MutableLiveData<Orders> getAllOrders(){
        Log.i("func","starting func");
        mAPIService.getOrders().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Orders>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i("func","onComplete");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i("onError",e.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Orders orders) {
                        Log.i("Repo",orders.toString());
                        allOrders.setValue(orders);
                    }
                });
        return allOrders;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<OrderRows> getAllOrderRows(){
        Log.i("func","starting func");
        mAPIService.getOrderRows().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<OrderRows>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i("func","onComplete");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i("onError",e.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(OrderRows orderRows) {
                        Log.i("Repo",orderRows.toString());
                        allOrderRows.setValue(orderRows);
                    }
                });
        return allOrderRows;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my question too, have you found any answers to this?